# Symfony Lock does not lock when making two requests from the same browser

Tags: php, symfony, locking, symfony-lock

I want to prevent a user from making the same request two times by using the Symfony Lock component. Because now users can click on a link two times(by accident?) and duplicate entities are created. I want to use the Unique Entity Constraint which does not protect against race conditions itself.

The Symfony Lock component does not seem to work as expected. When I create a lock in the beginning of a page and open the page two times at the same time the lock can be acquired by both requests. When I open the test page in a standard and incognito browser window the second request doesn't acquire the lock. But I can't find anything in the docs about this being linked to a session. I have created a small test file in a fresh project to isolate the problem. This is using php 7.4 symfony 5.3 and the lock component

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Lock\LockFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LockTest extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test")
     * @Template("lock/test.html.twig")
     */
    public function test(LockFactory $factory): array
    {
        $lock = $factory->createLock("test");

        $acquired = $lock->acquire();

        dump($lock, $acquired);

        sleep(2);

        dump($lock->isAcquired());

        return ["message" => "testing"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with the lock component but if your entity has a unique database constraint on it (besides id) then only one will ever be created.  Attempting to create another one will just cause an exception to be tossed.  So if preventing duplicate entities is all you need the review how to add a unique database constraint.

Comment: So you are opening the same page simultaneously twice in one browser, and see that in both cases lock is acquired, right? I think it's not that symfony lock component allows you to acquire one lock twice. It may be just regular php session locking: when two requests are run simultaneously, the first one acquires the lock, while the second is locked by the same session. When the first request is complete, the second is unlocked and also successfully acquires the lock. So first of all try to ensure that session is disabled.

Comment: Might try posting your question on [Symfony's Discussion Board](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions).  That will improve the chances of it being seen by a lock expert.  Also, I assume you are testing with an actual production server such as apache or nginx?  The development server is strictly a one request at a time and will certainly distort these sorts of things.

Comment: @Cerad the unique entity constraint of symfony is not a database constraint but a validator constraint. This gets checked at validation and not on insertion so race conditions can occur

Comment: @xtx yes i think it is locked to the session, does php lock requests to a certain session? Because in my use case the user is logged it but I want to prevent the user from clicking multiple times and creating duplicate entitites.

Comment: I will also try posting the question to the symfony discussion board. Thanks for the tip, did not know that that existed!

Comment: @bbos When one request with a certain session is handled by php, all other requests with the same session are locked (waiting). So for your particular problem, locks won't help. I think you're better off fixing this with 1) locking the button on the client side with js after the button is clicked (for the best user experience), 2) a unique database constraint (to protect data integrity)

Comment: I have tried the same now in a docker container instead of the Symfony Dev server but the problem still occurs. If a requests with the same session are locked those requests should be executed after each other right? This does not seem the case because in my use case a check is executed for duplicates and an insert is made after. So if the second request is locked until the first one finished the second should not pass the duplicate check right?

Comment: @bbos do you finally solved the problem?

Comment: I think it could be because of the stored used. With filestock it used the PHP `flock()` that probably only locks for different processes (my opinion, I don't know if it is true).

Comment: Using `DoctrineDbalStore` it runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly rewrote your controller like this (with symfony 5.4 and php 8.1):

```php
class LockTestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route("/test")]
    public function test(LockFactory $factory): JsonResponse
    {
        $lock = $factory->createLock("test");

        $t0 = microtime(true);
        $acquired = $lock->acquire(true);
        $acquireTime = microtime(true) - $t0;

        sleep(2);

        return new JsonResponse(["acquired" => $acquired, "acquireTime" => $acquireTime]);
    }
}
```

It waits for the lock to be released and it counts the time the controller waits for the lock to be acquired.

I ran two requests with curl against a caddy server.

```
curl -k 'https://localhost/test' & curl -k 'https://localhost/test'
```

The output confirms one request was delayed while the first one slept with the acquired lock.

```json
{"acquired":true,"acquireTime":0.0006971359252929688}
{"acquired":true,"acquireTime":2.087146043777466}
```

So, the lock works to guard against concurrent requests.

If the lock is not blocking:

```
$acquired = $lock->acquire(false);
```

The output is:

```json
{"acquired":true,"acquireTime":0.0007710456848144531}
{"acquired":false,"acquireTime":0.00048804283142089844}
```

Notice how the second lock is not acquired. You should use this flag to reject the user's request with an error instead of creating the duplicate entity.

If the two requests are sufficiently spaced apart to each get the lock in turn, you can check that the entity exists (because it had time to be fully committed to the db) and return an error.

Despite those encouraging results, the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html#usage) mentions this note:

> Unlike other implementations, the Lock Component distinguishes lock instances even when they are created for the same resource. It means that for a given scope and resource one lock instance can be acquired multiple times. If a lock has to be used by several services, they should share the same Lock instance returned by the LockFactory::createLock method.

I understand two locks acquired by two distinct factories should not block each other. Unless the note is outdated or wrongly phrased, it seems possible to have non working locks under some circumstances. But not with the above test code.

## StreamedResponse

A lock is released when it goes out of scope.

As a special case, when a [`StreamedResponse`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response) is returned, the lock goes out of scope when the response is returned by the controller. But the `StreamedResponse` has yet to return anything!

To keep the lock while the response is generated, it must be passed to the function executed by the `StreamedResponse`:

```
public function export(LockFactory $factory): Response
{
    // create a lock with a TTL of 60s
    $lock = $factory->createLock("test", 60);
    if (!$lock->acquire(false)) {
        return new Response("Too many downloads", Response::HTTP_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
    }

    $response = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($lock) {
        // now $lock is still alive when this function is executed
        $lockTime = time();
        while (have_some_data_to_output()) {
            if (time() - $lockTime > 50) {
                // refresh the lock well before it expires to be on safe side
                $lock->refresh();
                $lockTime = time();
            }
            output_data();
        }
        $lock->release();
    };

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');

    // lock would be released here if it wasn't passed to the StreamedResponse
    return $response;
}
```

The above code refreshes the lock every 50s to cut down on communication time with the storage engine (such as redis).

The lock remains locked for at most 60s should the php process suddenly die.

Comment: The problem is with the same session, for example, if you use the browser or you use the command `curl -b cookiefile -c cookiefile -k 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/test'` from different terminals so it uses the cookies.